# Error running command gradlew loadDefault

Tags: java, ofbiz

I'm a newbie in Apache OFBiz. When I try to run the coomand gradlew `loadDefault` I get the follow error:

```
C:\ISEP\ODSOFT\PL\Repositorio\ofbiz>gradlew loadDefault
:compileJava
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:createBaseTestServiceProviderJar
:processResources
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test
:check
:gitInfoFooter
:svnInfoFooter
:build
:ofbiz --load-data
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException :ofbiz --load-data
        at org.apache.ofbiz.base.start.Start.main(Start.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
:ofbiz --load-data FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ofbiz --load-data'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Any sugestions what could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that my username account in windows 10 had one space.
I follow [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_security/rename-user-account-folder-in-windows-10-preview/88033eca-6b32-47c5-90ac-a5e7af17d094?auth=1) tutorial and tried run the command again the error had disappear.

*Note*: Because this is for a university work, I had collages that had the same problem and with this, the problem disappear as well.